# Turn off lead assignment rules in salesforce lead trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I'm having trouble with a Salesforce lead trigger, fired after insert.  The lead assignment rules need to be **on by default**, but I need to bypass the rules for leads that match a certain criteria.

I've seen in the salesforce docs you are able to set assignment rules when inserting/updating leads: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm#assignmentRuleHeader_section

However, I'm not able to turn off these lead assignment rules:

```
...
// if criteria is met to skip assignment rules...
Lead tempobj1 = new Lead(id=objLead.id,OwnerId=ConDomainNameAndOwnerIdMap.get(Emaildomain),isOwnerChanged__c = true);

Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= false; //it's still running assignment rules!
tempobj1.setOptions(dmo);

...
...

update tempobj1;
```

I've also tried creating a new lead assignment rule set with no actual rules and set the DML options to use this - but the default assignment rules are still fired! `dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleID = '01Qe00000000HAq';`

The order of execution states the record is saved to database (not committed) > after triggers executed > assignment rules executed. So the trigger is run before assignment rules.

I've tried the code on before insert, but get the error 'DML statment cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old: Trigger.AssignOwnerToNewLead: line 133, column 1'

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Answer (score 2):

use this before trigger

```
for (Lead objLead : Trigger.new) {
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
        objLead.OwnerID = objLead.Eloqua_ID__c;
        objLead.setOptions(dmo);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the code I've tried, but does not work. Is this in a before insert trigger? I get an error when attempting this on before insert: 'DML statment cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old'

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new lead assignment rule with no assignments name it
  AssignmentSkip
- In apex programmatically set that id on the rule header options